# How to use CIMWFSServiceConnection in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, wfs, cartographic-information-model

Does anyone know how to add a WFS service to a map using the CIMWFSServiceConnection class?

The WMS and WMTS equivalents work perfect, but when using CIMWFSServiceConnection, the layer that's added to the map has a red exclamation mark in front of it, and the *Source* entry on the layer's properties dialog shows *Data source information not available*

This is the code I used for adding a WMS service, the only differences are the URL, and the class used in line 2:

```csharp
var serverConnection = new CIMInternetServerConnection { URL = "https://example.com/wms?service=WMS" };
connection = new CIMWMSServiceConnection { ServerConnection = serverConnection };
LayerFactory.Instance.CreateLayer(connection, MapView.Active.Map);
```

Adding a WFS through the user interface (i.e. Favorites > Add Item > New WFS Server) also works without problems.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I was missing is that you need to specify which FeatureType from the WFS you want to add as a layer. Presumably that would be specified by setting the LayerName:

```
connection = new CIMWFSServiceConnection { ServerConnection = serverConnection, LayerName = "myfeaturetype" };
```

However, that still fails for some reason.

In the ArcGIS Pro [snippet repository](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk/wiki/ProSnippets-MapAuthoring#add-a-wfs-service) I found this piece of code which *does* work:

```cs
CIMStandardDataConnection cIMStandardDataConnection = new CIMStandardDataConnection()
{
    WorkspaceConnectionString = @"SWAPXY=TRUE;SWAPXYFILTER=FALSE;URL=http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/services/SampleWorldCities/MapServer/WFSServer;VERSION=2.0.0",
    WorkspaceFactory = WorkspaceFactory.WFS,
    Dataset = "Continent",
    DatasetType = esriDatasetType.esriDTFeatureClass
};
```

Note that I am still on version 2.5, and I haven't tried the `CIMWFSServiceConnection` on newer versions. If anyone cares to do that, please let me know your results.